# Write less than greater than to text file in asp vbscript

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, special-characters, delimiter

I am having a very hard time trying to write out an xml file from asp vbscript to a text file using the Scripting.FileSystemObject.  The issue is the less than and greater than chars.  In order for me to add these characters to variables in the code i need to use &lt ;  &gt ;.  This causes a problem when writing the text.  The results look like this

```
&lt;copyright&gt;request copyright&lt;/copyright&gt;
&lt;lastBuildDate&gt;10/26/2012&lt;/lastBuildDate&gt;
```

proper format should be as such

```
<copyright>request copyright</copyright>
<lastBuildDate>10/26/2012</lastBuildDate>
```

Is there some sort of trick to converting those segments while writing the text file, or do i need to do something a bit more extravagant?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ive edited my question with what the appropriate output should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing in the [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx), you could just surround your variables with two calls to [Replace](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_replace.asp)

```
TextStream.Write Replace(Replace(myString, "&lt;","<"),"&gt;",">")
```

This way the variables aren't altered, but the written out data uses the right characters.

Comment: You the man! I tried 2 single replace lines which failed, but this worked like a charm.  Thanks a ton, now my xml looks nice and proper!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
objStream.Open
objStream.WriteText "testdata"
objStream.SaveToFile "C:\test.txt", 2
```

Comment: since filesystem object  save the data in Unicode or ASCII . for xml we would require UTF format